# Group two columns: 1st column as dict with keys as 1st column values, and 2nd column as dict values

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'length',1],
                   [1,'diameter',40],
                   [2,'length',5],
                   [2,'diameter',100]], columns=['no.', 'property','value'])
```

Or:

```
no.0 property   value
1    'length'   1
1    'diameter' 40
2    'length'   5
2    'diameter' 100
```

And I'm trying to convert it to dataframe like this (first column must be an index):

```
no.0 property
1    {'length': 1, 'diameter', 40}
2    {'length': 1, 'diameter', 40}
```

Comment: i dont understand your question. try rephrasing and make the title shorter and include more explanation in the question body.

Comment: I add examples because they describe my problem more properly than words

Comment: what does the last part of the code do? this part -> `df.groupby(['no.'])['property', 'value'].apply(
        lambda x: dict(zip(x['property'], x['value'])) )` ?

Comment: This is what I tried to do

Comment: okay, how do you get your dataframe? where do you import it from? csv file? please provide a sample source file (csv, etc.). Because, I think you dont need pandas at all for this. we can fix it from the file itself rather than making a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to `property` and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) on `no.` into `dict` to get inner `dict`:

```
new_df = (
    df.set_index('property')
        .groupby('no.')
        .agg(property=('value', lambda s: s.to_dict()))
)
```

`new_df`:

```
                           property
no.                                
1     {'length': 1, 'diameter': 40}
2    {'length': 5, 'diameter': 100}
```

---

Then [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) on the DataFrame to get the final output

```
d = new_df.to_dict()
```

`d`:

```
{1: {'property': {'length': 1, 'diameter': 40}},
 2: {'property': {'length': 5, 'diameter': 100}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Group by the `no.` column and create records inside a dict comprehension

```
{k: {'property': dict(g.values)} for k,g in df.set_index('no.').groupby(level=0)}


{1: {'property': {'length': 1, 'diameter': 40}},
 2: {'property': {'length': 5, 'diameter': 100}}}
```

---

If you want the output in `dataframe` format

```
df.set_index('no.').groupby(level=0)\
  .apply(lambda g: dict(g.values)).reset_index(name='property')


   no.                        property
0    1   {'length': 1, 'diameter': 40}
1    2  {'length': 5, 'diameter': 100}
```

Comment: Series format almost how I'm trying to do, but can you just change an existing dataframe? So there will be an index and column 'property'.

Comment: @neurocker I've edited the answer. We have to `reset` the index to convert series to dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot the dataframe, then drop the column level, create dictionary for each row, and finally call `to_dict()`:

```py
reshaped = df.pivot(['no.'],['property'],['value'])
reshaped.columns = reshaped.columns.droplevel()
reshaped.apply(lambda x: {'property': dict(x)}, axis=1).to_dict()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
{1:
     {'property':
          {'diameter': 40, 
           'length': 1}},
 2: {'property':
         {'diameter': 100, 
          'length': 5}}
 }
```